# Getting img src with Scrapy gets weird results, why?

Tags: python, scrapy, src

I'm trying to webscrape https://celulares.mercadolibre.com.ar/ with Scrapy 1.4.0. What I want to obtain is a list with description of the product along with the img src of that product.
The problem is that when I run my spider it returns appropiately just the first 4 items (description + corresponding img src) and the rest of the item list is just the description with "none" img src.
By analyzing the webpage source code I can tell that the only difference between the first 5 items and the rest is that the class attribute of the first ones it's called "lazy-load" while the other ones have an special id like "ML2178321".
But considering that I don't refer the class name in the spider code I don't understand why the behaviour changes in this last items.
I suspect about some JQuery/JS thing that I'm not aware.
Here's the code of one of the first item containers:

```html
<div class="image-content">

 <a href="https://articulo.mercadolibre.com.ar/MLA-644049024-samsung-galaxy-j7-prime-lector-de-huella16gb3gb-ram-_JM" class="figure item-image item__js-link"> 
 
 <img alt="Samsung Galaxy J7 Prime Lector De Huella+16gb+3gb Ram" src="https://http2.mlstatic.com/samsung-celulares-smartphones-D_Q_NP_771296-MLA25977210113_092017-X.jpg" class="lazy-load" srcset="https://http2.mlstatic.com/samsung-celulares-smartphones-D_Q_NP_771296-MLA25977210113_092017-X.jpg 1x, https://http2.mlstatic.com/samsung-celulares-smartphones-D_NQ_NP_771296-MLA25977210113_092017-V.jpg 2x" width="160" height="160"> 
 
 </a> 

</div>
```

And here the code of the container from one of the later images (the ones that return "None" img src):

```html
 <div class="image-content">
 
 <a href="https://articulo.mercadolibre.com.ar/MLA-643729195-motorola-moto-g4-4ta-gen-4g-lte-16gb-ram-2gb-libre-gtia-_JM" class="figure item-image item__js-link"> 
 
 <img alt="Motorola Moto G4 4ta Gen 4g Lte 16gb Ram 2gb Libre Gtia" id="MLA643729195-I" srcset="https://http2.mlstatic.com/motorola-celulares-smartphones-D_Q_NP_765168-MLA26028117832_092017-X.jpg 1x, https://http2.mlstatic.com/motorola-celulares-smartphones-D_NQ_NP_765168-MLA26028117832_092017-V.jpg 2x" src="https://http2.mlstatic.com/motorola-celulares-smartphones-D_Q_NP_765168-MLA26028117832_092017-X.jpg" width="160" height="160"> 
 
 </a> 
 
 </div>
```

Lastly, here is the code that I'm running

```
import scrapy
import time

class MlarSpider(scrapy.Spider):
name = "mlar"
allowed_domains = ["mercadolibre.com.ar"]
start_urls = ['https://celulares.mercadolibre.com.ar/']

def parse(self, response):
    SET_SELECTOR = '.results-item'
    for item in response.css(SET_SELECTOR):

        PRODUCTO_SELECTOR = '.item__info-title span ::text'
        IMAGEN_SELECTOR = '.image-content a img'

        yield {
            'producto': item.css(PRODUCTO_SELECTOR).extract_first(),
            'imagen': item.css(IMAGEN_SELECTOR).xpath("@src").extract_first(),
        }

    NEXT_PAGE_SELECTOR = '.pagination__next a::attr(href)'
    next_page = response.css(NEXT_PAGE_SELECTOR).extract_first()
    if next_page:
        yield scrapy.Request(
            response.urljoin(next_page),
            callback=self.parse
        )
```

I've implemented the Barmar comment and got it working like a charm. Just added this lines to my spider:

```
        IXPATH= '@src'
        if item.css(IMAGEN_SELECTOR).xpath(IXPATH).extract_first() is None:
            IXPATH = '@data-src'
        yield {
            'producto': item.css(PRODUCTO_SELECTOR).extract_first(),
            'imagen': item.css(IMAGEN_SELECTOR).xpath(IXPATH).extract_first(),
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no `src` attribute in the later images. Here's the code of that image:

```
<img width='160' height='160' alt='Motorola Moto G4 4ta Gen 4g Lte 16gb Ram 2gb Libre Gtia' id='MLA643729195-I' class='loading' title='https://http2.mlstatic.com/motorola-celulares-smartphones-D_Q_NP_765168-MLA26028117832_092017-X.webp' data-src='https://http2.mlstatic.com/motorola-celulares-smartphones-D_Q_NP_765168-MLA26028117832_092017-X.webp' data-srcset='https://http2.mlstatic.com/motorola-celulares-smartphones-D_Q_NP_765168-MLA26028117832_092017-X.webp 1x, https://http2.mlstatic.com/motorola-celulares-smartphones-D_NQ_NP_765168-MLA26028117832_092017-V.webp 2x' />
```

The image URL is in the `data-src` attribute, not `src`.

The site is using a lazy loading plugin that waits for the user to scroll an image into the viewport before setting the `src`. At that time it copies the `data-src` attribute to `src`. What you posted is apparently the DOM element *after* this has happened, not the original HTML source, which is what `scrapy` sees.

You could simply change your script to look for `data-src` attributes if it can't find a `src` attribute.

Comment: I applied your solution and worked fine. Thanks! But I want to know more about your answer. The data-src attribute can be seen by inspecting the webpage with a browser? is it part of the html code or the plugin/js code?

Comment: Use `View Source` in the browser to see it, this shows the same HTML that Scrapy gets. It's part of the HTML.

Comment: Oh. I was doing it by inspecting the elements I wanted to scrap. Thank you very much! :)

Comment: Elements shows the DOM after Javascript has made its modifications. Scrapy doesn't execute JS.